# update a variable in background in bashrc

Tags: bash, command-prompt, background-process

I would like the variable `NUSERS='who | wc -l'` to be updated every 2 seconds in order to display the number of connected users in the prompt with `PS1='\u@\h-${NUSERS}:\w $'` defined in the `.bashrc` file.

I tryed: `watch NUSERS='who | wc -l' &>/dev/null &` in the `.bashrc`... it didn't work

I tryed: `while true; do NUSERS='who | wc -l' && sleep 2; done &` in the `.bashrc` ... it didn't work neither

I don't understand why this doesn't work. I would like to avoid screen and nohup because I don't want the command to run when I exit the ssh session.

Comment: The parent shell doesn't see the variable updates in its children.

Comment: Note that `bash` cannot update the prompt between commands, so if you really want the count updated every 2 seconds, displaying it in the prompt is not the way to go (unless you are running commands every two seconds). Either run `watch` in a terminal window, or use a program like `screen` or `tmux` which provides a status bar which *can* be updated at a fixed interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, it is possible to insert a command directly in the `PS1` variable declaration in the `.bashrc` file

```
PS1='\u@\h-`who | wc -l`:\w $'
```

Answer (score 3):

The parent shell doesn't see the variable updates in its children.

Since your purpose is to have an update *not every two seconds*, but *each time a new prompt is displayed*, you may use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable for this.

As per the reference manual, about the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable:

> If set, the value is interpreted as a command to execute before the printing of each primary prompt (`$PS1`).

Exactly what you need!

Put this in your `.bashrc` file:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='NUSERS=$(wc -l < <(who))'
PS1='\u@\h-$NUSERS:\w $'
```

and you'll be good.

Comment: Although if every user had this in their prompt on a system with many users, it might make sense for the sysadmin to create a dedicated service to keep this number up to date in a common location.

Comment: @tripleee sure, but that's way beyond the OP's question…